# Android, Bluemix Error 401 : You are not authorized

Tags: android, connection, database-connection, http-status-code-401, ibm-cloud

I downloaded the sdk from [here](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/mobile/index.html#index), created an application but when i run the app the logcat notifies:

Error 401, Failure: You are not authorized.

I tested the Bluemix app with the sample code you can find [here](https://hub.jazz.net/project/mobilecloud/bluelist-mobiledata/overview%20%22), obviously switching the default parameters with my app's ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

I downloaded the April jars, the most recent ones. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error sounds as if the Mobile Application Security (MAS) is not set up correctly.  Could you try going to your mobile back end on Bluemix, clicking the MAS service, turning the "Enable Client List" switch to on, and then adding your bundle id under iOS?  Additionally, confirm that you've copied the client-id & client secret correctly into the properties file for the application.